# How to submit a form using JS with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a rails project that is using the `refile` gem to process file uploading, and I would like to submit a form after the user has selected the file in their file browser.

I created a button in the navbar of the rails app, and have the following form.

**_nav.html.erb**

```
<div class='upload-image'>
          <form name="form_upload_image">
          <p>Upload Image <i class="fa fa-upload"></i></p>
        <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |form| %>

              <%= form.attachment_field :tshirt_image, direct: true, class: "fa fa-upload", input_html: { hidden: true, onchange: "uploadImage()" } %>

          <%= form.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

        <% end %> <!-- form -->
      </form>
        </div>
```

I would like to call the `uploadImage` JS function once the user has selected the `Open` button within the file browser.

I created a `navbar_image_upload.js` file within the `app/assets/javascripts` which looks like the following,

```
// app/assets/javascripts/navbar_image_upload.js

function uploadImage() {
  document.forms["form_upload_image"].submit();
}
```

However, when I select the file in the file browser and choose `Open` it's not submitting the form.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be better binding your `change` method with an [unobtrusive pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), as using inline JS is almost certainly going to lead to issues with delegation etc:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("change", "input.fa-upload", function(e){
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

You'll also be best to use the correct formatting for the form:

```
<%= content_tag :div, class: 'upload-image' do %>
    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |form| %>
        <%= form.attachment_field :tshirt_image, direct: true, class: "fa fa-upload", input_html: { hidden: true } %>
        <%= form.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `uploadImage` is not being called? Assuming it is, it's submitting the parent form, `form_upload_image`.

You probably didn't intend to nest forms; the `form_for` helper renders a form tag itself. That is the form you actually want to submit.

You should take a look at the rendered output. You probably have more form elements than you expect.